# How to store loop result into array in VBScript?

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a loop, and I want to put the result into array.
Here is my loop.

```
    For i = 1 To bill
        a = rs("CT08_Tarikh") 'from db
        cutiumum = Array(a)   'and this is how I declare array
        rs.MoveNext
    Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

and after that, i will pass the variable to another function:

```
tarikh = NetWorkdays(dateFrom, dateTo, cutiumum)

Public Function NetWorkdays(dtStartDate, dtEndDate, arrHolidays)
```

but, when I try to do some loop for `arrHolidays` inside the function `NetWorkdays`, it only return 1 data (not all from the `cutiumum`).

What do you think is my mistake?

**Update**

I'm already using

```
dim arrRecordset

arrRecordset = rs.GetRows()
```

but I got an error inside the function

```
Public Function NetWorkdays(dtStartDate, dtEndDate, arrHolidays)
    Dim lngDays
    Dim lngSaturdays
    Dim lngSundays
    Dim lngHolidays
    Dim lngAdjustment
    Dim dtTest
    Dim i, x

    lngDays = DateDiff("d", dtStartDate, dtEndDate)
    lngSundays = DateDiff("ww", dtStartDate, dtEndDate, vbSunday)
    lngSaturdays = DateDiff("w", IIf(Weekday(dtStartDate, vbSunday) = vbSaturday, dtStartDate, dtStartDate - Weekday(dtStartDate, vbSunday)), dtEndDate)

    For x = LBound(arrHolidays) To UBound(arrHolidays)
        For i = 0 To lngDays
            dtTest = DateAdd("d", i, dtStartDate)

'error in line here: Subscript out of range: 'arrHolidays'
            If arrHolidays(x) = dtTest And Weekday(dtTest) <> 1 And Weekday(dtTest) <> 7 Then
                lngHolidays = lngHolidays + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If Weekday(dtStartDate, vbSunday) = vbSunday Or Weekday(dtStartDate, vbSunday) = vbSaturday Then
        lngAdjustment = 0
    Else
        lngAdjustment = 1
    End If

    NetWorkdays = lngDays - lngSundays - lngSaturdays - lngHolidays + lngAdjustment
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dim arrRecordset
arrRecordset = rs.GetRows()
```

The *getRows()* method will transform a recordset into a two dimensional array in one go:

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_getrows.asp

Comment: it looks good , but I got an error . I already update my question and if you could take a look, i appreciate.

Comment: Is this the same array you create with getRows()? In that case it might be because the array is two-dimensional. You need to provide UBound and LBound with a dimension: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_lbound.asp

Comment: These problems are easy to find if you use a debugger. Do you have (free) Visual Studio installed? You can use it to debug ASP. Add the word "stop" somewhere in your ASP code, and VS will break there. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525253(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Ok. I will. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a more detailed explanation on how to debug asp with VS. https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/debugging-classic-asp-with-visual-studio